# Can iOS and Android receive data from each other using Bluetooth(specifically BLE)

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

If an app on one OS(say iPhone) broadcasts a token(let's say a string) over BLE to its physcial surrounding, can the same app on the other OS(say Android) receive this token?

According to Google, iOS and Android cannot connect over Bluetooth? But does connect mean no exchange is possible b/w them?

Comment: Yes, they can. If you have a compatible app running on both devices. "Broadcasting" an identifier is tricky though. They can discover each other, connect and exchange identifiers

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely possible. In fact, Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) is one of the few ways you can use to communicate wirelessly between iOS and Android. There are many links that go over this:-

- [Working with Bluetooth Low Energy across Android and iOS](https://www.dca-design.com/latest/working-bluetooth-low-energy-across-android-and-ios)
- [Developing Bluetooth Low Energy on Android and iOS](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/bluetooth-low-energy-android-ios-development)
- [iOS Tutorial: Connecting Android and iOS](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/ble-chat-connecting-android-and-ios.66543/)